# How can I check an app is now uninstalled?

Tags: android, uninstallation

How can I check an app is now uninstalled after clicking on uninstall button ?
I want to remove the adapter after uninstall app
I use `adapter.remove(item)` but my adapter removed even when I cancel the uninstalling

```
if(condition for an uninstalled app){
  adapter.remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know when an app is uninstalled just register a `BroadcastReceiver` on [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).

Note that this is intended only for being notified about the removal of other apps, **not** your own, as the documentation states:

> The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.